# How Token Interceptor work in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, token, interceptor

Struts2 provide Token Interceptor for ensures that only one request per token is processed, But, I don't understand how it works, if a user send the one request twice what happens? Does the user get an invalid token or get response of the first request? What is a logic behind this interceptor?

Comment: The source for TokenInterceptor is like 50 lines of Java, along with the token tag whose output can be seen, it shouldn't take particularly long to understand what's happening--I suggest exploring this as an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `token` interceptor returns the result `invalid.token` when an invalid token is found. The logic is simple: it uses a session to save a *valid* token per request and when intercept it checks it by comparing one that sent and other that is from session.