# Token interceptor overrides fileupload interceptor when used together

Tags: struts2, token, struts

I am using token interceptor and fileupload interceptor in struts2.
But when I upload a file larger than the configured one fileupload returns input but instead of getting redirected to the one which is defined in result mapped to fileupload it is redirecting to the result mapped to invalid.token.

I have tried altering the sequence of interceptors but nothing worked.

```
<action name="something" class="something">
<interceptor-ref name="token"/>
<interceptor-ref name="fileupload"/>
<result name="invalid.token" type="redirect">someaction</result>
<result name="input" type="redirect">someaction</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Hi Pawan. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add configuration (struts.xml). You may want to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17808701/573032