# I am working in Struts2 webapp and while trying to send mail it's not working on first click where as second click working

Tags: java, struts2, token, interceptor, jquery-ajax

I am working in Struts2 webapp and while trying to send mail it's not working on first click where as when I clicked second time it's working and aslo if I comment the `<interceptor-ref name="token" />` then it's working on first click.

**NOTE:** 1. On first click working only if I comment`<interceptor-ref name="token" />`

Here's my `struts.xml` code

```xml
<action name="myActionName" class="actions.myActionName"
            method="myActionName">
            <interceptor-ref name="token" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
            <exception-mapping result="passRecoveryException"
                exception="exceptions.PasswordRecoveryException" />
            <result name="success" type="json" />
            <result name="passRecoveryException" type="json" />
            <result name="invalid.token">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

and I'm sending mail from frontent using jquery

```
$(document).on('click','#myActionNameId',function(){
    if($("#username").val() == ""){
        showToaster(2,"This field is required."," User name");
        return false;
    }else if ($("#email").val() == ""){
        showToaster(2,"This field is required."," Email ID");
        return false;
    }/*else if ($("#captchaText").val() == ""){
        showToaster(2,"This field is required."," Captcha");
        return false;
    }*/else if(grecaptcha.getResponse().length==0){
        showToaster(2,"Please verify your captcha","Captcha");
        return false;
    }
    
    else{

        $('#loading').show();
        var form = $('#forgotPassForm');
        var formdata = false;
        if (window.FormData){
            formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
        }
        var formAction = form.attr('action');
        submitByAjaxWithConfirmwithCallBackJSON(formAction,formdata,function(data){
            //alert(data.exception);
            if(data.exception==undefined){
                 if(data.success==true){
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    showToaster(1,data.message.split(':')[1],data.message.split(':')[0]);
                 }else{
                     showToaster(2,data.message.split(':')[1],data.message.split(':')[0]);
                     $('#loading').hide();
                 }
            }else{
                var msg = data.exception.message.split(':');
                showToaster(2,msg[1],msg[0]);
                //alert(msg[0]);
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        })
    }
});
```

on first click it's going to

```
 if(data.success==true){
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    showToaster(1,data.message.split(':')[1],data.message.split(':')[0]);
                 }else{
                     showToaster(2,data.message.split(':')[1],data.message.split(':')[0]);
                     $('#loading').hide();
                 }
```

**else** part but after second time when I again click to send it's working fine.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself what the "token" interceptor does.

Comment: The token interceptor is used to prevent calls to the action until the sametoken  is generated between different action calls. AFAIK to solve double-submit problem you need to put a token interceptor in front of the action and it doesn't allow to resubmit the same form twice. If you use ajax to send a token then make sure it is updated for the next usage of the form.

Comment: @RomanC I meant after clicking on send button it throws error i.e., data.success is false, then after when I click again on submit it sends, though I tried all as you suggests

Comment: @SurajNath If you get `data.success` then it's already showing you a success callback. If it's not a business logic problem then you should check for message errors. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17808701/573032) is how a token interceptor works.